# Angular exported model typescript has no members in generated JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For this simple Typescript class used as a model in Angular 5 project

```
export class Category
{
    id: string;
    label: string;
}
```

the generated code does not have any members

```
"use strict";
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "a", function() { return Category; });
var Category = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Category() {
    }
    return Category;
}());
```

I'm trying to deserialize json into a list of Category objects using the json-object-mapper or json-typescript-mapper node modules, neither works because there is no generated member in the JS code for the model.

Adding a constructor

```
constructor() {
    this.label = '';
}
```

seems to work - understandably - but why without the ctor there is no generated member? There seem to be so many examples of constructor less angular models that supposedly work. Could there be some sort of optimization due to angular's AOT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A declaration is just a direction to the typescript compiler to allow usage of the member with that type. As long as you don't assign anything to the member, no JS will be emitted. This does not mean there is anything invalid, in JS you can use the field (JS doe snot care that the field did not previously exist on the class, when you first assign it)

If you initialize the field when you declare it, JS will be emitted to initialize the field:

```
export class Category
{
    id: string= '';
    label: string = '';
}
```

Will emit :

```
var Category = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Category() {
        this.id = '';
        this.label = '';
    }
    return Category;
}());
```

Comment: It is a bit counter-intuitive I must say, though when I think of the same declarations without a type, i.e. just "id;label;" it makes sense.